# Is there a replacement for the Handler class?

Tags: android

I love the convenience of the Handler class; I can easily queue messages and even delay messages. However, all the code runs on the UI thread which is causing stuttering of the animation.

Is there a class, like Handler, that doesn't run on the UI thread ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use a [`HandlerThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html). I do not have a simple example of this handy, unfortunately.

Personally, I tend to use `java.util.concurrent` classes directly for things that do not involve the main application thread (e.g., `LinkedBlockingQueue`, `ExecutorService`).

Comment: Mark, thanks for taking the time to respond to my question. I should have been more specific: what I'm really looking for is a message queue that provides all of the convenience of a Handler but without running on the main/UI thread. I've currently implemented a basic LinkedBlockingQueue and worker thread but I wonder if there's a well-tested class out there for me to use.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere: "that provides all of the convenience of a Handler but without running on the main/UI thread" -- um, I think `HandlerThread` does that. "I've currently implemented a basic LinkedBlockingQueue and worker thread but I wonder if there's a well-tested class out there for me to use." -- actually, `LinkedBlockingQueue` is probably better tested than `Handler`, simply because it's part of standard Java and therefore has been beaten up a fair bit.

Comment: Thanks for directing me to the LinkedBlockingQueue; I found a nice example here: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/blockingqueue_example.shtml  I guess I got distracted by the `Looper` in your code sample because I remember reading somewhere that anytime the Looper is used, the main thread comes into play.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere: Um, yeah, that would be because the code sample I had there had nothing to do with `HandlerThread`. ::smacks forehead:: Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by the currently accepted answer which seems to imply that using `Handler` on a non-UI thread isn't possible, because it's something I've done quite routinely and I thought it was pretty well known.

Within a non-UI `Thread`:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        ...
        mThreadHandler = new Handler() {            
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                    ...
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        Looper.loop();
    }
```

Using the `mThreadHandler`, messages can be sent to be processed by the `Handler` in the above non-UI `Thread`.

If there are any good reasons for not using the `Handler` / `Message` classes to post work to be done on a non-UI Thread in this way then I'd like to know. It has been working fine for me so far though. The only reason I've read for not using a `Handler` in this way is that "a `Handler` is meant for posting stuff to the UI thread" which is not in itself a good technical basis.